# How can I update the bios of my gigabyte ex58 ud4p motherboard?

Tags: bios, updates

Virtual PC docs say I have to disable trusted execution or update bios.

I am running a gigabyte ex58 ud4p motherboard.

How can I update the bios, is it risking what I have installed on my system now?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the bios update from their website:

> http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/Motherboard/BIOS_Model.aspx?ProductID=2986

To update your bios download the latest version and execute it (it's an executable).

Quote from that link:

> **Warning**:
>   Because BIOS flashing is
>   potentially risky, if you do not
>   encounter problems using the current
>   version of BIOS, it is recommended
>   that you not flash the BIOS. To flash
>   the BIOS, do it with caution.
>   Inadequate BIOS flashing may result in
>   system malfunction.

The worst that can happen is that you fry your motherboard, but that doesn't mean you lose your data and what's installed on your system. Replacing the motherboard will give you everything back.